# related to website hosting and remote accessing

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting

I want to open the web site with hosting server is in remote location but i got the error like this

Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: the web config file like this  <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>  this section will appears before   ***Notes****

Comment: Its working now sorry for any distrubance caused by me

Comment: could you please tell us how you fixed this problem? I am seeing same error.

Comment: @Sutikshan   at that time i have mailed to company who is hosting my website.....they have solved my problem.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to add below line to get to know exact error. (as suggested by the error msg itself.

```
  <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/> </system.web>
```